# Why my python SIGPROF doesn't work?

Tags: python, signals

I am installing the SIGPROF signal and execute the handler every 2 seconds. Is there any problem?

```
  1 #!/usr/bin/env python
  2 #-*-coding: utf-8 -*-
  3 #pylint: disable=W0141,W0613,W0603
  4 
  5 import os
  6 import sys
  7 import signal
  8 import time
  9 
 10 def myhandler(signum, frame):
 11     print "myhandler"
 12     sys.stdout.flush()
 13 
 14 signal.signal(signal.SIGPROF, myhandler)
 15 signal.setitimer(signal.ITIMER_PROF, 2, 2)
 16 print signal.getitimer(signal.ITIMER_PROF)
 17 
 18 while True:
 19     print "sleeping 1..."
 20     sys.stdout.flush()
 21     time.sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those timers only decrement when the process is executing, since it's mostly sleeping it takes very long for the timer to expire, if you remove the sleep it should work fine, from the [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/signal.html#signal.ITIMER_PROF):

> signal.ITIMER_PROF
>       Decrements interval timer both when the process executes and when the system is executing on behalf of the process. Coupled

Try:

```
while True:
    for i in xrange(100000):
        pass
```

Answer (score 1):

No, it works as expected. As stated by [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/signal.html#signal.ITIMER_PROF), ITIMER_PROF

> decrements interval timer both when the process executes and when the
>   system is executing on behalf of the process. Coupled with
>   ITIMER_VIRTUAL, this timer is usually used to profile the time spent
>   by the application in user and kernel space. SIGPROF is delivered upon
>   expiration.

Since the `sleep` call causes the process to do nothing, the timer is decremented very slowly. Get rid of the sleep:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#-*-coding: utf-8 -*-
#pylint: disable=W0141,W0613,W0603

import os
import sys
import signal
import time

def myhandler(signum, frame):
    print "myhandler"
    sys.stdout.flush()

signal.signal(signal.SIGPROF, myhandler)
signal.setitimer(signal.ITIMER_PROF, 2, 2)
print signal.getitimer(signal.ITIMER_PROF)

while True:
    continue
```

And then when it is run you can see the signal working:

```
$ python prof.py 
(2.004125, 2.000125)
myhandler
myhandler
```

If you want to time it in 'real' time (its not clear from the question what you're aiming to do) rather than processor time, use [ITIMER_REAL](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/signal.html#signal.ITIMER_REAL) and catch the `SIGALRM` signal instead.